# iText 7 SVG as a background

Tags: java, svg, itext7

I'm trying to add a background in a PDF using Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg). Initially the recommended way was to transform the SVG into an Image object and then use scaleToFit to get it to the right size, then add it to the document. This works partially as it transforms the small and scalable SVG into a Bitmap. Next I've made a PdfFormXObject in order to get back the scaling by having it drawn on each page. However, now it does not display anything at all.

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(backgroundBytes);
PdfFormXObject svg = SvgConverter.convertToXObject(inputStream, pdf);
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getFirstPage());
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
canvas.addXObject(svg, rect);
```

How should I be adding SVG backgrounds to iText 7 PDFs? Can this be done properly in the first place? I have not been able to find good code examples.

Update:

Here is the code for converting the SVG to a properly scaled Image. The issue with this is that it works for adding the image, but it adds it as an element so it pushes everything else down.

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(svgAsBytes);
Image image = SvgConverter.convertToImage(inputStream, pdf);
image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
int totalPages = pdf.getNumberOfPages()+1;
for(int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < totalPages; pageNumber++ ) {
    document.add(image);
}
```

Comment: Hi, adding an image as a background can actually mean different things in different use cases. Do you want to tile up the background if the image is smaller than the space of the canvas, do you want to stretch the image or do you want to not do anything at all and just place the image on a canvas? Please attach screenshots of the desired behavior and the behavior which you described as "destroying scaling". Otherwise it's hard to understand what you really want to achieve

Comment: I have an SVG which covers an A4 sized page and I want to repeat it as a background on every page. When converting it I used the PageSize.A4 width and height initially and that didn't work. Then I used scaleToFit which made it an image, but adding it to the page pushes all other elements down. Preferably I would not convert it to an image at all and leave it as SVG.

Comment: Do you generate the whole document yourself, or do you modify an existing document and adding the background images there? In your code sample you have `document` instance but it's important to know how you create it and whether the underlying `PdfDocument` is created with reader and writer or writer only.

Comment: Examples just used new PdfDocument(). I tried the iText 7 pdfHtml module with a html template before this, but that didn't work at all as 90% of css was ignored so I was trying out iText 7. It seems it requires extensive knowledge of PDF standards and iText 7 itself to do simple things so it's not maintainable and therefore not an option for my company unfortunately. I'll leave the question open in case someone finds a sensible answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have a similar Problem. I am trying to add a SVG image as a table cell background. The problem is that i can not scale the image. Here is my code:

```
InputStream triangleSteam = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/AH-AddressTriangle.svg");
Image triangle = SvgConverter.convertToImage(triangleSteam, pdfDocument);
//triangle.setHeight(UnitValue.createPointValue(127.83f));
//triangle.setWidth(UnitValue.createPointValue(78.63f));
triangle.scaleAbsolute(78.63f, 127.83f);

Cell headerCell_12 = new Cell();
headerCell_12.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
headerCell_12.setPadding(0f);
headerCell_12.setHeight(UnitValue.createPointValue(127.83f));
headerCell_12.setWidth(UnitValue.createPointValue(78.63f));
headerCell_12.setNextRenderer(new ImageBackgroundCellRenderer(headerCell_12, triangle));
headerTable.addCell(headerCell_12);
```

And here ist the BackgroundCellRenderer I am using:

```
protected class ImageBackgroundCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    Image img;

    public ImageBackgroundCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, Image img) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new ImageBackgroundCellRenderer((Cell) modelElement, img);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        try {
            img.scaleToFit(getOccupiedAreaBBox().getWidth(), getOccupiedAreaBBox().getHeight());
            drawContext.getCanvas().addXObject(img.getXObject(), getOccupiedAreaBBox());
            super.draw(drawContext);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The background is added but the image is not scaled (see picture)

[Screenshot from Adobe Illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFBQx.jpg)

The SVG becomes even bigger that it actually was!

Thank you!